# isomorphism of (co)tangent space

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces, co-tangent-space

Let $X$ and $Y$ be Riemann surfaces. $f:X→Y$ be analytic map. Suppose $f$ induces  isomorphism $f*$ between (co)tangent spaces, then, $∀p∈X$, $f'(p)≠0$.

How can I prove(understand) this?

P.S. Such $f$ is called local analytic isomorphism, and if $f$ is bijective, then from holomorphic inverse function theorem, $f$ is proved to be isom between $X$ and $Y$ as Riemann surfaces.

Comment: If $f'(p)= 0$, then locally the map looks like $f(z) = z^nh(z)$, where $n\ge 2$ and $h$ is analytic.

Comment: Thank you, but If so, what contradicts the assumption?